# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Affix and Youtube Issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any reason why Affix spazzes out when there is a youtube embedded on the page? The left sidebar (which is what I'm affixing) doesn't affix when you scroll. In the second screenshot, I hovered over the sidebar to get a couple elements to pop up so you could see it. I removed the youtube video and it worked just fine. I can post more specific information if needed... I just could not find any resources online where this particular issue was brought up.

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to the current page or re-create the error on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: No problem. What's quite strange is that it's working for me in Safari and Firefox but not it Chrome. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Same. It's a real head-scratcher. Bootstrap guys on Github wanted nothing to do with this question!

Comment: I've narrowed it down a bit, hopefully won't be much longer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to the `.sidebar-affix` class.

The reason is that `.ytp-force-transform` has the following styles:

```
-moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

and this was impacting the rendering of the sidebar. The simple fix is just to add the `translate3d(0,0,0)` style to the sidebar so youtube's css no longer interferes with it.

Here's a good explanation of what `translate3d(0,0,0)` does: http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/

Comment: Joe, Thank you VERY much for your help. It would have taken me hours to narrow it down to that!

Comment: @pep - no problem at all, it wasn't an obvious one!